# Are there graphic card problems when upgrading to ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ati, 13.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my laptop having ATI graphic card. I tried ubuntu 12.10 before on this same laptop and I encountered a lot of problems with unity (due to lack of support for my GPU in linux version used by 12.10). I want to know if I'll face same problems if I upgrade my 12.04 version to 13.04 ?

Comment: Ubuntu is not responsible for AMD dropping support for any given graphic cards model in Catalyst, so if you upgrade to an even newer release of Ubuntu it probably still won't be supported.

Answer (score 1):

Your mileage may vary.  I updated my home desktop with an ATI/AMD 6750 HD card this weekend and saw no issues.  I'm not using the fglrx or catalyst however and strictly using the builtin with mesa.  If you're using proprietary drivers, I'd wait.  A good check is to boot in the live mode via usb and mess with it there.

Good luck :)